# Is it OK to send request params in https header?

Tags: https, http-headers

I know that, We shouldn't mixing the headers and request parameters.Headers are used for passing meta information.

But anyway, Is it OK to send query string in header? I don't want to display query string in URL...

*Note: I am using HTTPS...*

Comment: Why not just use a POST request and send in the body?

Comment: It work but, I want to send request with same URL, But different HTTP verb,So...